# mvvmcross xamarin android full fragging

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

My xamarin android project uses fragments so i added the dll "Mvvmcross - MvvmCross.HotTuna.Droid.FullFragging 3.5.1" from nuget. When i tried to build my project, i am getting the following errors. Not sure whats wrong. Could someone help me please.Attached screenshot shows the references that i have for my project. [image]

```
Error XA4204: Unable to resolve interface type 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.IMvxView`1<TViewModel>'. 
Are you missing an assembly reference? (XA4204)Error XA4204: Unable to resolve interface type 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView`1<TViewModel>'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (XA4204)
```

Comment: Make sure all packages are the same version.